# I want to surf the net with my laptop without connecting to wifi

Tags: wireless-networking

I want to surf the net with my laptop without connecting to wifi, wherein I can browse with my lappy at any place... so how will I do that?

Comment: Please clarify, you don't want to connect to **any** WiFi or **open/public** WiFi?

Comment: Not mentioned: you could use a USB modem and a telephone land line, which would be pretty widely available.  You would need an ISP that still offers that service.  "Surfing" would not be an accurate description of your activity (it's 1,000x slower than WiFi).  You might be able to do things that are mainly text-based, like check email if you have a lot of time.  I suspect that most modern web sites wouldn't work in a useful way at that speed.  But it's an emergency option.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have:

1. A smartphone (and carrier) that supports tethering
2. A laptop (or 3G dongle) that supports SIM cards

There is no way, however, if your phone (and carrier) does support tethering, then:

In Android 4.4+:

`Settings > Tethering & portable hotspot > USB tethering`
OR
`Settings > Tethering & portable hotspot > Portable WiFi Hostpot`

In iOS:

`Settings > Personal Hotspot`

If your laptop DOES support SIMs, then:

1. Everyone who gets physically access to the SIM card can use it, because the SIM PIN will be stored into the SIM card. Therefore, we do not recommend this option.
2. It's also possible to input the SIM PIN automatically by configuring the 3G modem.
   Open the device manager and double click on your 3G modem device
   [image: Device Manager]
3. Under `Extra initialization commands` write `AT+CPIN="your SIM PIN"`
   [image: Extra]
4. Click OK
5. Reboot
6. From now one, the SIM PIN is input automatically during the boot up process and there should not be a request from the SIM PIN any more.

### Creating the (3G) Dial Up connection:

1. Log on as Local Admin
2. Open `Network and Sharing Center`
3. Click on `Set up a connection or network`
4. Click on  `Set up a dial up connection`
   [image: Reference]
5. Input the Dial in String into the Dial-up phone number field. For most carriers, the string  `*99****1#`  or `*99#`  will work. In case of dial in problems, please ask your SIM card provider for the Dial in String.
   [image: Reference]
6. Input User name and Password. For most carriers, these fields can be left empty or filled with a dummy. However in case of  dial in problems, please ask your SIM card provider.
7. Input a Connection name if you  like
8. Check the `Allow other people to use this connection` checkbox
9. Click connect
10. Wait until a connection is made.
    [image: Reference]
    [image: Reference]

Answer (score 0):

That's literally impossible to do.

For you to surf the Internet, you have to be connected to the Internet. For you to connect to the Internet, you need to either connect to Wi-Fi or plug in an Ethernet wire to your computer.

Since you specified that you don't want to be connected, the only way that you can achieve what you want is to browse cached pages of the Internet, a feature deprecated in Windows from Windows 7 and up, and is nonexistent in other operating systems. Basically, your problem is analogous to "I want to microwave my food without it being in the microwave."

Case and point: **You can't.** Unless you want to use your phone as a hotspot, then that's a whole different story... ([iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204023)) ([Android](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/mobile-phone/how-tether-google-android-phone-image-3279408/))

Answer (score -1):

Well... you can't, assuming you mean no wireless access at all.

You could maybe hook up a 3G adapter, or a phone acting as ethernet, but if you mean total lack of connection to anything but still wanting to access it? No, that's not possible, because you can't connect to the servers of the world without having any connection.